# Changes in Maui Blazor Navigation

Tags: maui-blazor

As of now it has been about a year since I decided to use MAUI Blazor to develop my cross platform app. Something about Blazor seems more appealing than xaml pages with it's code behind. Early in the process page navigation was something I tried to resolve. The "hybrid" adjective to the name indicated, at least to me, that it should be possible to navigate back and forth between a razor page and xaml. Whatever solution I was working on in those early days I remember having a method in NavMenu so full of commented out instructions that didn't work that it made finding the latest line being tried difficult to find. So I dropped it and focused on Blazor  thinking that maybe what I want isn't ready for prime time yet.

While recently following a demo by Gerald Versluis the very navigation I wanted was demonstrated. So, dutifully, I built a new solution and tried it. It worked. Thinking that maybe a library or package I added to my app spoiled the navigation ability I started porting over bits of the application I was building. Nothing broke the ability navigate to a xaml page. So I tried again in the bigger app and it worked.

So my question is did something change as MAUI Blazor evolved that the incremental releases corrected? Or is that just a conspiracy theory I developed over my frustration to make hybrid navigation work?  Or was the provision there all along and I missed something important that only fed my frustration?

Comment: Currently, you can refer to [Blazor Hybrid routing and navigation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/hybrid/routing?view=aspnetcore-7.0&pivots=maui) on how to use navigation in `MAUI Blazor`.

Comment: @Alexander May, thanks for the reference. All of my links are internal. Considering the timing of your reply and the date of the article, I'm suspecting that you are one of the contributing authors.

Comment: Thanks for the response! If you need any other help, don't hesitate to reach out, I'm glad to help you!